# Get file path of imported module

Tags: node.js, typescript, annotations, node-modules

I'm writing a class decorator for my controllers. It looks like:

```
export function Controller<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }> (ctor: T) {
    return class extends ctor {
        public readonly name = name;
    }
}
```

`ctor` is a constructor of a class decorated with `@Controller`.

Full path to the controller's file is `src/modules/{module}/controllers/{ctrl}Controller.ts`. I need to get parts in curly braces and concatenate them into `{module}.{ctrl}`.

To do so I need a filepath of module from which `ctor` is imported. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get file path information from `ctor` parameter. It's just a function that was defined somewhere.

Basically, `module` and `ctrl` preferably have to be provided to controller class on registration, since the path is known at this moment, i.e.:

```
  for (const filename of filenames) {
    const Ctrl = require(filename).default;
    const [moduleName, ctrlName] = parseCtrlFilename(filename);
    Ctrl._module = moduleName;
    Ctrl._name = ctrlName;
  }
```

The only and hacky workarount is to get file path of a place where `Controller` was called. This is achieved by getting stacktrace, e.g:

```
const caller = require('caller-callsite');

export function Controller<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }> (ctor: T) {
    const fullPath = caller().getFileName();
    ...
}
```

The problem is that it's the path where `Controller` is called:

*.../foo.ts*

```
@Controller
export class Foo {...}
```

*.../bar.ts*

```
import { Foo } from '.../foo.ts';

// fullPath is still .../foo.ts
export class Bar extends Foo {}
```

A less hacky and more reliable way is to provide file path explicitly from the module where it is available:

```
@Controller(__filename)
export class Foo {...}
```

There is [`import.meta` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) which is [supported by TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-for-importmeta). It depends on Node project configuration because it works with `esnext` target:

```
@Controller(import.meta)
export class Foo {...}
```

`import.meta` that was passed to `@Controller` can be consumed as `meta.__dirname`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed and thorough answer. I'll use your advice and provide the module+ctrl information on importing the module.